# The Subbase $\tau_{A}$ of a topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $\delta$ be a subbase of $\tau$ on X and $A\subset{X}$. I wish to show that $\delta_{A}=\{A\cap{S}\mid S\in\delta\}$ is a subbase for $\tau_{A}$ on A.

Comment: What are condtions a family of sets must have to be a subbase? Try checking the one-by-one and show your progress.

Comment: @ Mr/Mrs wroobell, any family S of subsets of X is the subbase for a unique topology on X [i.e, finite intersection of members of S forms a base for the topology $\tau$ on X]

Comment: @Brian. A lot of thanks!

Comment: That is not true, and not the point of exercise. We have here two distinct topological spaces - $(X, \tau)$ and $(A, \tau_A)$ where $\tau_A$ is a subspace topology on $A$. Now, we are give some subbase $\delta$ of $\tau$. We want to show that $\delta_A$ is a subbase of $\tau_A$. What are conditions that F \subset \tau_A has to have to be a subbase?

Comment: @wroobell That's true but is there any way I could prove it?

Comment: I think the family should be finite.

Comment: Use definition of subbase, the fact that we know that $\delta$ is a subbase of $\tau$ and how the open subsets of $(A, \tau_A)$ look like.

Comment: No, that most often won't be the case.

Comment: Try starting by writting down all the definiions that are mentioned in the exercise.

Comment: Subbasis: Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space. A subset S of \tau is said to be subbasis for \tau if the set$ \beta={B|B is the intersection of finitely many members of S}$ forms a base for $\tau$

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Let $\tau_1$ be the topology on $A$ generated by $\delta_A$; you want to show that $\tau_1=\tau_A$.

- Use the fact that $A\cap S\in\tau_A$ for each $S\in\delta$ to show that $\tau_1\subseteq\tau_A$.

Showing that $\tau_A\subseteq\tau_1$ is a little harder. I suggest the following approach. (Others are possible.)

- Let $\varnothing\ne U\in\tau_A$. Show that for each $x\in U$ there is a $B_x\in\tau_1$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U$; then $U=\bigcup_{x\in U}B_x\in\tau_1$.

You’ll need to use the fact that there is a $V\in\tau$ such that $U=A\cap V$. It will also be convenient to let $\beta$ be the base for $\tau$ generated by $\delta$, i.e., the family of all subsets of $X$ that are intersections of finitely many sets in $\delta$ and note that there is a $B\in\beta$ such that $x\in B\subseteq V$.

Comment: @Mr Brian. Thank you very much! @ Mr wroobell, I'm grateful!

Comment: @user359540: You’re very welcome.